# setTimeout in a loop with 3 functions to be executed after the previous one completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout, deferred

I 3 functions a(), b() and c() to be executed in a loop x times as follows:
I have to call function a(); after a() completed, I have to wait s1 seconds before calling function b(); after s1 seconds have elapsed, I have to call function b(); after b() completed, I have to wait s2 seconds before re-starting the loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
a();
setTimeout(b,s1);
setTimeout(function() {},s2);
}
```

However with the above-mentioned loop functions a() and b() are not correctly executed. They are executed irrespective of the previous function has completed or not.

I also tried with:

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
// create a deferred object
var r = $.Deferred();

// do whatever you want (e.g. ajax/animations other asyc tasks)
a();

setTimeout(function () {
    // and call `resolve` on the deferred object, once you're done
    r.resolve();
}, s1);

// return the deferred object
return r;
};

var FunctionTwo = function () {
    b();
};

for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
setTimeout(FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo),s2);
}
```

but it doesn't work as desired.

Can you help me please?

---

EDIT

---

functions a() and b() are as follows:

```
function a() {
$.ajax({
        type: $('#form1').attr('method'),
        url: 'Misura',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            if($.trim($('#nomeMisura').val()) == "") {
                alert('<%= labels.getString("nomeMisuraObbligatorio") %>');
            $('#nomeMisura').val("");
            return false;
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#misura').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#pulisci').attr('disabled', false);

        misurazioneInCorso = true;
    }
});
```

}

```
function b() {
$.ajax({
    type: $('#form1').attr('method'),
    url: 'Pulisci',
    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        var numeroCampioniMisurazione = Number(data.delta.campione2) - Number(data.delta.campione);
        //visualizzo in tabella le misurazioni
        $('#tabellaMisurazioni').append('<tr id="Misurazione"><td>'+data.nomeSessione+'</td><td>'+data.nome+'</td><td>'+data.delta.campione+'</td><td>'+data.delta.campione2+'</td><td>'+numeroCampioniMisurazione+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f1+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f2+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f3+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f4+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f5+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f6+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f7+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f8+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f9+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f10+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f11+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f12+'</td><td>'+data.delta.t1+'</td><td>'+data.delta.t2+'</td><td>'+data.delta.to+'</td><td>'+data.delta.ft+'</td><td>'+data.delta.rh+'</td></tr>');
        $('#tabellaMisurazioni tbody tr:first').html('<td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td>');

        $('#misura').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#pulisci').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#esportaCsvMisurazioni').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#nomeMisura').val('');

        misurazioneInCorso = false;
    }
});
```

}

So, i think a() and b() are asynchronous functions.

Comment: What's not working as desired in the second approach? Is `a` synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I am proposing is very similar to Kevin Nelson's code. In my code, the "control logic" is not "included" in the application functions.

You may find a PDF version of my "solution" -- it includes an "analysis" and the code may be found at the end -- in the following link: http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/1415708506.pdf.

The following was generated from the PDF document.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this solution will work as I desire because a() and b() functions includes asyncrhonous AJAX calls. For example, in your function PL1() I need that a() completes all its tasks before setTimeout(PL2,s1) is invoked.

Comment: I don't know why but your solution seems to work :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some kind of scheduler : below i use a most simple stack that contains either a function or a time to wait before next task execution.
Code below is untested, but might give you ideas :

```
var tasks =  [];         // list of all tasks / wait time
var currTaskIndex = 0;  
var looping = true;

function runTask() {
   if (currTaskIndex==-1) return;
   var currTask = tasks[currTaskIndex];
   // iterate
   currTaskIndex++;
   if (currTaskIndex==tasks.length) {
        if(looping ) {
           currTaskIndex=0;
         } else {
           currTaskIndex=-1;               
         }
   }
   // run task / wait
   if (typeof currTask == "function") {
      currTask.call(null);
      runTask();
   } else {
     // currTask is a time -> wait
     setTimeout(runTask, currTask);
   }
}
```

Use with

```
tasks.push(a);
tasks.push(s1);
tasks.push(b);
tasks.push(s2);

runTask();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Asyncrhonous calls, you always need to put the "next move", which is contingent on the result of the asynchronous activity, into the callback method that is called when the asynchronous activity ends.

Per your comments, your methods contain asynchronous ajax calls.  Your setTimeout calls are also asynchronous.  If you call:

```
setTimeout(b,s1);
setTimeout(c,s2);
```

then both timeouts will run simultaneously.  This means you are entering the world of "callback hell"...it's not as hard as some people seem to make it out to be, IMHO, but it is a different way of thinking.

To prevent subsequent methods from executing and to prevent your loop from just going to the next iteration and doing the entire loop at once, you need to call b at the end of a and c at the end of b.  You also have to wait for the end of c before you start your next iteration, which means looping after c is done, not putting c inside of a loop...otherwise, your loop is going to just zip through all x iterations immediately and you're going to have all your methods running almost at once (excepting `a()` since it's a synchronous call, given my previously mentioned assumption).  So, what you need to do is something along the lines of:

```
var i = 0;
var x = 100;

function a() {
    //end our loop inside the method
    if( i++ < x ) {
        //shortening your ajax call to just success method
        var ajaxSuccess = function (data) {
            $('#misura').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#pulisci').attr('disabled', false);

            misurazioneInCorso = true;

            setTimeout(b,s1);
        }
    }
}
function b() {
    //shortening your ajax call to just success method
    var ajaxSuccess = function (data) {
        var numeroCampioniMisurazione = Number(data.delta.campione2) - Number(data.delta.campione);
        //visualizzo in tabella le misurazioni
        $('#tabellaMisurazioni').append('<tr id="Misurazione"><td>'+data.nomeSessione+'</td><td>'+data.nome+'</td><td>'+data.delta.campione+'</td><td>'+data.delta.campione2+'</td><td>'+numeroCampioniMisurazione+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f1+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f2+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f3+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f4+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f5+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f6+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f7+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f8+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f9+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f10+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f11+'</td><td>'+data.delta.f12+'</td><td>'+data.delta.t1+'</td><td>'+data.delta.t2+'</td><td>'+data.delta.to+'</td><td>'+data.delta.ft+'</td><td>'+data.delta.rh+'</td></tr>');
        $('#tabellaMisurazioni tbody tr:first').html('<td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td>');

        $('#misura').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#pulisci').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#esportaCsvMisurazioni').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#nomeMisura').val('');

        misurazioneInCorso = false;

        setTimeout(c,s2);
    }
}
function c() {
    //do your stuff, then loop back to a
    a();
}

a();
```

Notice, the ONLY thing I'm doing is putting your "next call" into the success method of your AJAX call, and I'm looping by having `c()` call `a()` rather than putting it into a `for()` loop.  Then, I modified `a()` so that it will end the loop after `x` iterations by not executing inside the `if()` I placed there. This will ensure that they go in order.

Comment: I edited my first post with a() and b() functions. They seem to be asynchronous functions ($.ajax calls). I haven't had time to try any proposed solution yet. I don't know which one is suitable for asynchronous functions.

Comment: Updated to use callbacks from ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=5;
outerFun(){
    if(x){
        a();
        setimeout(function(){
            b();
            setTimeout(function(){
                //do its part
                x--;
                outerFun();
            },s2);      
        },s1);
    }
}
```